# Need help understanding 'RejectedExecutionExemption'

Tags: android, android-asynctask, threadpool

I am running some async tasks and 1 of my users is crashing with a RejectedExecutionExemption:

**Stack Trace**

```
stackTrace: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@5e2675f rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@f5f25ac[Running, pool size = 9, active threads = 9, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 240]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:794)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1340)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:607)
```

**The Line causing the exception**

```
 new SetDownloadStatusTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Two Part question here really..

1. I'd like like some help understanding the first line of the exception:

   ThreadPoolExecutor@f5f25ac[Running, pool size = 9, active threads = 9, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 240]

   pool size vs. active threads vs quad tasks.. I assume I am executing too many tasks, but am unsure how to determine this really for those three variables.  If someone could break that down for me, Id appreciate it.
2. If this is the case that I am running out of threads, should I increase the amount allowed and if so how, or is there a better solution.

**Custom AsyncTask**

```
private class SetDownloadStatusTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, DownloadStatus> {

        @Override
        protected DownloadStatus doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return bookDownloadManager.status(product);
        }


        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(DownloadStatus downloadStatus) {
            updateMenuForDownloadStatus(downloadStatus);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I assume I am executing too many tasks

Correct.

> If someone could break that down for me, Id appreciate it

`AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`, on a quad-core CPU, will support nine parallel threads (`pool size = 9`). That is backed by a `LinkedBlockingQueue` of maximum length 128. And, you have requested your 138th simultaneous task, so we are out of threads (`active threads = 9`) and the queue is full (`queued tasks = 128`).

> should I increase the amount allowed and if so how, or is there a better solution

You should be asking yourself "why in the name of all that is holy am I trying to download 138 things at once?".

If there is a legitimate need for that, use your own custom `Executor`, rather than `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`. If there is not a legitimate need for 138+ simultaneous downloads — and, frankly, that number seems insane — then change your code to avoid doing that, such as cancelling tasks that you no longer need.

Comment: would be great if these details are updated in the Threads chapter of the book .

Comment: @OBX: Assuming that "the book" refers to [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android), see page 534 of Version 8.2.

Comment: hmm, I tried downloading it with IDM , and I got v 8.0, downloading 8.2 now the hard way

Comment: @OBX: The same material is in Version 8.0, though I don't have a page number handy. It's in the chapter on Threads, as you suggested. Search for `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

Comment: Ok , got it anyway now . Thanks :)

Comment: how did you arrive at 138th requested task? also, the user could have somehow started a ton of download requests, nothing I can do about that.. should I just surround it with a try catch to prevent a crash.

Comment: @erik: "how did you arrive at 138th requested task?" -- max capacity is 9 + 128 = 137. Hence, the `RejectedExecutionException` will occur for the 137 + 1 = 138th parallel request. "nothing I can do about that" -- then perhaps you should not be using `AsyncTask`. Downloading hundreds of things may take longer than the user wants to sit around in your activity. Use a `Service`, with its own `ThreadPoolExecutor`, so that you can both control the queue behavior *and* worry less about your process being killed before the downloads complete.

Comment: Im sorry.. I misspoke these aren't downloads them selves but instead download statuses being update